# Get Start and end date of Week according to string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display the start date and end date of the week. **I have One date and a string like 1W4 and,in 1W4 consider 4 weeks and 1 visit** so, my string like this 2W4,1W2,3W3,1W1,2W4.

I want to make start date and end date of week array according to string and **week start from Sunday to Saturday**.

Please post me if anyone has solution.Please ignoring if mistake in asking Question.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear? can you show us implementation or share some code so we can guess what's the issue.

Comment: want to make week start and end date array and consider week according to string.

Comment: Maybe you can use Carbon for this : https://carbon.nesbot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try my php code:

From [php.net datetime.format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

- W: ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday.
- The  first  calendar  week  of  a  year  is  that  one  which  includes  the  first  Thursday  of  that  year.

So I have to rest one day to the start week date.

I assumed that the weeks correspond to the current year.

Input string:

```
$weeksString = "2W4,1W2,3W3,1W1,2W4";
```

Code:

```
<?php

$weeksArray = explode(",", $weeksString);

$result = array();

foreach($weeksArray as $visitsWeek) {
    list($visits, $week) = explode("W", $visitsWeek);

    $startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y") . "W" . str_pad($week, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . " -1 days"));

    $endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate . " +6 days"));

    $result[] = array("week" => $week, "startDate" => $startDate, "endDate" => $endDate);
}

?>
```

Output array $result:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'week' => '4', 'startDate' => '2021-01-24', 'endDate' => '2021-01-30', ), 1 => array ( 'week' => '2', 'startDate' => '2021-01-10', 'endDate' => '2021-01-16', ), 2 => array ( 'week' => '3', 'startDate' => '2021-01-17', 'endDate' => '2021-01-23', ), 3 => array ( 'week' => '1', 'startDate' => '2021-01-03', 'endDate' => '2021-01-09', ), 4 => array ( 'week' => '4', 'startDate' => '2021-01-24', 'endDate' => '2021-01-30', ), )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,works perfectly,but in my case start date fixed and if week 4 then add week start date and end date according to 4 weeks, if 2 weeks then add  2 weeks.

Comment: You are welcome! So, you have one start date and want to add to it 1 week, two weeks, etc, is this correct? You can do something like this inner my loop to calculate start date: '$startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fixDate . " +n days"))' where n is: week number * seven.